# No ID returned for NodeRepository::getList

Tags: magento2

In a custom command I'm trying to retrieve the ID of the existing Hierarchy Nodes. In the DB I have 2 rows for the table magento_versionscms_hierarchy_node with ID 1 and 16. But in the code when I call `$result = $this->nodeRepository->getList($criteria);` with empty criteria (`$criteria = $this->criteriaBuilder->create();`) the variable `$result` has 2 items with the values except for the node_id column.

Preconditions

1. Magento Enterprise Edition version 2.3.0

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the `getItems` function:

```
$result = $this->nodeRepository->getList($criteria)->getItems();
```

To **`getId`** using `foreach loop`:

```
$nodes = [];
foreach($result as $node){
     $nodes[$node->getId()] = $node;
}
```

Comment: You are correct this returns the array of results, but the Ids are missing.

`array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(8) {
    ["page_id"]=>
    int(19)
    ["identifier"]=>
    NULL
    ["level"]=>
    int(1)
    ["sort_order"]=>
    int(0)
    ["request_url"]=>
    string(7) "explore"
    ["xpath"]=>
    string(2) "91"
    ["scope"]=>
    string(7) "default"
    ["scope_id"]=>
    int(0)
  }
}`

Comment: how about adding `->getId()` ?

Comment: NodeRepository::getList() generates a collection of array data and not objects. So it is not possible to call methods on the individual items.

Comment: using a loop? I think it is possible

Comment: The following


`foreach($result as $node){
                    var_dump(gettype($node));
                    var_dump($node);
                }`

gives :
string(5) "array"
array(8) {
  ["page_id"]=>
  int(19)
  ["identifier"]=>
  NULL
  ["level"]=>
  int(1)
  ["sort_order"]=>
  int(0)
  ["request_url"]=>
  string(7) "explore"
  ["xpath"]=>
  string(2) "91"
  ["scope"]=>
  string(7) "default"
  ["scope_id"]=>
  int(0)
}

so $node->getId() will throw an error

Comment: which repository are you using for the nodeRepository? Is it the menu or the node itself?

Comment: I'm using this repository class: Magento\VersionsCms\Model\Hierarchy\NodeFactory